# How to reference Mono C# assemblies with GWAN C# servlets

Tags: dll, mono, g-wan

I am trying to include a c# servlet CompanyListService.cs in gwan csp folder and getting a compile error 'The type or namespace name `PropertyManagement' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?'

PropertyManagement.sql.dll is in the same folder. Also tried to install it in GAC and no luck.

if use, 'mcs CompanyListService.cs -r:PropertyManagement.Sql.dll', it resolves the assembly

Existing Hello.cs and Loan.cs working fine. Any help will be appreciated?

Thanks
Ram

```
// C servlet example for the G-WAN Web Application Server 
// http://gwan.ch/
// hello.cs: G-WAN supports .NET C# servlets

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
//using PropertyManagement.Sql;
//using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;

public class CompanyListService
{
   public static int Main(string[] args)
   {
    PropertyManagement.Sql.CompanyRepository Repository = new PropertyManagement.Sql.CompanyRepository();
    List<PropertyManagement.Sql.Company> CompanyList = Repository.GetCompanyList();

    //string json = JsonSerializer<List<Company>>(CompanyList);

        Gwan.xbufCat(Gwan.getReply(args[0]), "test");
        return 200; // HTTP status (200:'OK')
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation does not mention it but [loading dynamically your assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/625115/1079036) is not only possible but will offer more flexibility than the [traditional ways to do it](http://www.mono-project.com/Assemblies_and_the_GAC).

After all, that's what shared libraries are for. Kudos to C# for not having missed that point.

Besides, G-WAN looks for Mono libraries under the `/usr/lib/mono` path and for user-defined assemblies (like the G-WAN API by the way) in the `/gwan/.../libraries/cs` directory.

Comment: Thanks for the Quick reply. I tried to add the dll to GAC and also tried copy the dll to /usr/lib/mono and sub folders and still not able to resolve the reference. I am not sure about performance when loading assemblies using reflection or dynamic loading. any suggestions to make the shared dlls work with gwan?

Comment: Loading dynamic libraries is either done by you manually or by the Mono runtime - either way, it will take as much time and you can use a flag to do it only the first time a servlet is executed. Did you try copying your C# DLL to the dedicated **/gwan/.../libraries/cs** directory? That's where G-WAN's API is defined, and it is properly resolved.

Comment: I've put it in GAC, /cs, /usr/lib/mono - it doesnot resolve, while code changes in gwan_api reflecting

Comment: Using one of the G-WAN scripts at startup, you can load the library in the G-WAN memory-space, and then register its functions in the G-WAN API C# class exported in the /gwan/.../libraries/cs directory. Then your servlets will be able to use any extended C code you wrote, whether this is G-WAN C API function C# wrappers or your own C functions.

Comment: when you compile servlets - what pkg-config do you use?

Comment: We don't modify anything either in the system or in the mono runtime settings.

Comment: If you add special pkg-config while compiling, I could add there libraries I need. $mcs hello.cs -pkg:dotnet

Comment: Also I found that gwan compiles only gwan_api.cs file, not any other names in libraries/cs folder.

Comment: Since mono does not support the **pragma** keyword (nor any equivalent) we would have to use a comment at the top of the source code file to specify dependencies (like Google Go if I remember well). If you are interested in testing such a feature, contact the G-WAN team to get a test release.

Answer (score 0):

Per the request of another G-WAN + C# user (Igor), the following features have been added in G-WAN v4.12.21:

- $MONO_PATH is created to include the directory
  /.../[gwan]/libraries/cs/dll
- *.dll files located under [gwan]/libraries/cs/dll
  are added with -pkg:lib1,lib2...
- any library specified by the line:

  // pragma link libname[,libname,...]

  ...in a *.cs source code file is added with the "-pkg:" switch.

Hope it helps.