# User control related third party control dependencies in client application

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have built a wrapper on top of a third-party grid (eg: Infragistics, Telerik). I have provided the dependent dlls along with my wrapper dll to the client application (as the wrapper doesn't expose all the properties of grid). I have the following questions:

1. Can I give my user control to client with out giving my third-party dependent dlls?
2. Can my client application can use my third-party control as a third-party control?

Answer (score 0):

1. No, you can't. In theory it may possible to [merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222655/embedding-assemblies-inside-another-assembly) assemblies into one (there will be no original third-party dll files on the client machine). But

   - Third-party (e.g. Telerik) API will be available on the client machine - nothing will be hidden.
   - This may not work depending on third-party. For example, part of dll files can be native, code may rely on having original assembly files etc.
   - This is most likely illegal, even for most open-source licenses.

If third-party is open-source or you have purchased component with source code, it's easy to isolate relevant code and license allows this - just copy code in your project.

2. Sure. In VS just add reference to project with your component/[GAC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) registered assembly with your component/compiled dll. You will be able to use your component. Note: original third-party grid related dlls should still be provided with this app.