# Class Library As Embedded Resource In A Class Library

Tags: c#, dll, embedded-resource

I have a C# class library that compiles to a DLL. My class library also references another class library DLL.

I need to add the dependency DLL as an embedded resource so I only have 1 DLL file. This file is a plugin for software I have no control over and the software will not resolve the dependency DLL properly.

I have found example of adding class libraries to Windows Forms projects but cannot find how to add a class library as an embedded resource in a class library project.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/625115/1338915

Comment: Use the GAC or implement the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve event or use ILMerge.

Answer (score 0):

Add the assembly to your project as a regular file rather than a reference at the root of the project (it can be anywhere but it's easier to put it there for this explanation).

Click on it in the solution explorer, and in the properties window set the 'Build Action' to 'Embedded Resource'.

You can use the following code snippet to load the assembly at runtime (remember to change the string passed into GetManifestResourceStream):

```
        using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("TestProject.MyAssembly.dll"))
        {
            if (stream == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot find resource.");
            }

            using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
            {
                var rawAssembly = new byte[(int)stream.Length];

                reader.Read(rawAssembly, 0, (int)stream.Length);
                var assembly = Assembly.Load(rawAssembly);

                // Do what you want with the assembly
            }
        }
```

Comment: So if my code currently looks like this how would I change it to implement what you described?

`using EmbeddedAssembly;

namespace MainClassLibrary
{
    public partial class MyCustomControl : UserControl
    {
  public MyCustomControl()
  {
   var widget = new EmbdeddedWidgetControl();
  }
 }
}`

Sorry for the noobish questions. I have never used Embedded Resources before.