# Resources Files in Multiple Languages

Tags: visual-studio, build, castle-activerecord

I'm working on a c# Visual Studio project I've taken over and one thing that is causing me a problem is that a package Castle.Components.Validators is installing every single resource file it has when I build for every single language it knows about.  This means that in my eventual program directory I have folders for about 12 different languages.  I don't want all those as it clutters things up and tbh I don't use the Validator resource files.  How can I stop it including all those resource files?

Cheers,

Neil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there might be a more elegant way to deal with this Problem, but an easy one that'll work would be to add a post-build-script to your project, that deletes all the unnessecery files and folders.

Greetings

Juy Juka

Comment: Yes that was my last resort; I've tagged the castle people to see if they've dealt with this before.  If it were a webapp it wouldn't matter but a client app's folders looks messy with all the language folders there.  If I could even tuck them away in a directory that'd be OK.

Comment: Hello Neil Benn, you could use ILMerge ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222655/embedding-assemblies-inside-another-assembly ) but A) that doesn't remove the assemblies, just hides them and B) is probably also a post-build-skript. Greetings Juy Juka