# SISS package gets corrupted while using custom dlls

Tags: c#, ssis, embedded-resource

I've created a SSIS package (SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2013) for importing some data. Long story short, I need to embeed some dlls to be called in runtime using this method:

[Embedding assemblies inside another assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222655/embedding-assemblies-inside-another-assembly)

Tried outside SSIS script component and is working.

Problem is, when you try to add a .dll as a resource the package gets corrupted and throws

[image: this error]

Is there any workaround to use custom assemblies into a SSIS package without deploying them or fix this error?

Thank you

Comment: What dlls are you trying to add? Have you checked if the target framework of the dll is the as the script component?

Comment: Custom dlls. Both dlls and script component using .Net 4.5.2

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is because the .dll is stored as bytes in the XML file of the package, and probably finds some character not allowed.

The workaround was transform that .dll into a Base64String, embeed it as a resource on the project and then do the way back.